# Where can I put my json file

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a json file and I shoul read/write it. First, I tried to read from assets but this way I can't write during runtime. Then i did this:

```
string path = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
string fileName = Path.Combine(path.ToString(), "myFile.json");

if(File.Exist(fileName)){
    //do something
} else {
    File.Create(fileName);
    Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName); //This returns "/storage/sdcard0"
}
```

But where should I put my json file? In "/storage/sdcard0"? Where is it?

Comment: into root directory.

Comment: You can put files in getExternalStorageDirectory(), getFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDir(); You can also supply the file in assets and then copy from assets to one of those dirs.

Comment: `In "/storage/sdcard0"? Where is it?` If you write a file to that directory then the file is in that directory. In  "/storage/sdcard0". Where else ? Strange question.

Comment: So I should rewrite it into new file with 'Write()' method? But can't i acces there physically?

Comment: Copy your json file in assets folder of res.

Comment: Anything included in the app bundle is read only - the bundle cannot be written to at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to bundle the `myFile.json` file into the assets and copy it to a writable location when the app starts for the first time:

The following code provides a helper class for you:

```
public class FileAccessHelper
    {
        public static string GetLocalFilePath(string filename)
        {
            string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string o= Path.Combine(path, filename);
            return o;
        }

        public static void CopyAssetFile(string path, string fileName)
        {
            using (var br = new BinaryReader(Application.Context.Assets.Open(fileName)))
            {
                using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                    int length = 0;
                    while ((length = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        bw.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So in the main activity you can use it like this:

```
var path = FileAccessHelper.GetLocalFilePath("myFile.json");
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    CopyDatabase(path, myFile.json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you set a breakpoint and examine the value of path variable?
In this way you can get the actual path where the json file is saved.